# PHP Lagger Handler Help

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, logging

i wanted some way of handling my errors and emailing it to me just i started using and testing the php lagger: http://code.google.com/p/lagger/ although i'm having some problems with it when it comes to not show the error and mail sending.

When the error first happens it sends an email but afterwards it stops and i have to delete the skip page so it can send it again. Anyone have any clues why it happens?

Other thing, when i do something like this:

```
$errors->addAction(new Lagger_Action_Exception(), 'notice,warning,fatal');
try {
    throw new Exception("ERRO");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $exceptions->handle($e);
}
```

it display the errors to the users, i just want it to update the log error and send me an email.

Any ideas? Is it any configuration or something?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

This is really a product specific question. I have had a quick look over the code for lagger and it isn't too complicated. I think it be best that you look at how it all works and modify it for your own purposes.